# How to post a request to get cookie values and post new request by the previously obtained cookie By using Go language?

Tags: go

How to post a request to get cookie values and post new request by the previously obtained cookie By using Go language

here first post request is generating a variable `cookie` in the form `[SID=pcmPXXx+fidX1xxxX1cuK; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict]"`

but i can't send this cookie to another post request (getting error).

sample go file with comments

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "strings"
  "net/http"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http/cookiejar"
)

var client http.Client
func init() {
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Got error while creating cookie jar %s", err.Error())
    }
    client = http.Client{
        Jar: jar,
    }
}

func main() {

  urlx := "http://localhost:8080/api/v2/auth/login"
  methodx := "POST"

  payloadx := strings.NewReader(`username=admin&password=strongadmin`)

  client := &http.Client {
  }
  reqx, err := http.NewRequest(methodx, urlx, payloadx)

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  reqx.Header.Add("Referer", "http://localhost:8080/")
  reqx.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36")
  reqx.Header.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")

  resx, err := client.Do(reqx)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer resx.Body.Close()


  cookie := resx.Cookies()
  fmt.Println(cookie)

  bodyx, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resx.Body)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Println(string(bodyx))






  //second request start here 
// this var cookies is a dummy cookie that i manually written,
// i need to replace the below variable 'cookies' to previously obtained variable 'cookie' without error





  cookies := &http.Cookie{
      Name: "SID",
      Value: "PW16gD0Ja0OqixXeqpQle1WC/OK19tj+",
      MaxAge: 300,
  }
  url := "http://localhost:8080/api/changes"
  method := "POST"

  payload := strings.NewReader(`json=%7B%data=valuex%22%3A%22300%22%7D`)

  clientx := &http.Client {
  }
  req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
//  req.Header.Add("Accept", "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*")
  req.Header.Add("Referer", "http://localhost:8080/")
  req.Header.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
  req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36")
  req.Header.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
  req.AddCookie(cookies)
  res, err := clientx.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer res.Body.Close()

  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)

//second request end here

}
```

Comment: You've received raw cookie string, so add it using `req.Header.Add("Cookie", cookie)` on next request

Comment: replacing `req.Header.Add("Cookie", cookie)` will give error `cannot use cookie (type []*http.Cookie) as type string in argument to req.Header.Add` as expected, cause cookie value is in between `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first request You're getting cookies as:

```golang
cookie := resx.Cookies()
```

- which is slice of Cookie struct `[]*http.Cookie`

then if You want to use them in next request do loop over them and add:

```golang
for _, c := range cookie {
  req.AddCookie(c)
}
```

check [this example](https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/http/Request/AddCookie/golang-request-addcookie-method-examples.html)

Comment: ok thanks buddy you just saved my another 12 hours, one last doubt what is the difference between `for _, c :=...` and `for c :=...`

Comment: @AnasS read here for better understanding https://go.dev/play/p/fINUtdV9AZa